# Vertical line spacing with mixed font sizes in beamer item list

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment, fontsize, itemize

I cannot get a consistent line spacing in beamer when having multiple font sizes in itemise environment. Adding `\par` does not help. Could anyone please help me? TIA!
Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
  \item item 1
  \item {\LARGE item 2 \par}
  \item item 3
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

It produces the following:[image: Vertical spacing before and after item 2 is inconsistent.]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `\par` forces a linespacing suitable for `\LARGE` which is exactly what you do not want here:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
  \item item 1
  \item {\LARGE item 2}
  \item item 3
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! What I also found important is the region to surround by braces. It should NOT be `\LARGE{item 2}`, but rather `{\LARGE item 2}`. Otherwise, the spacing is inconsistent again.

Comment: @ted_kingdom no latex size command takes an argument `\LARGE{item}` is the same as `\LARGE item` and applies the size change to the rest of the document or the end of some containing environment. (just as `\bfseries {item}` would make the rest of the document bold, not just `item`)